# Smart contract Ethereum - How to recreate same contract after used selfDestruct()

Tags: function, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Is it possible to destroy (using selftDestruct function) and generate the same contract at the same time ?

We assume that the first contract is to have 1Eth and then withdraw all eth to another erc20 address, after the complete withdrawal, the first contract calls the selfdestruct function and then the same contract is redeployed, and that in a loop.

Maybe the simply way is to use a conditional function?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible "at the same time", need to do it in separate transactions.

<del>`selfdestruct` prevents later operations on the contract from being executed, and flags the contract for deletion.</del>

`selfdestruct` stops the execution in its current scope, and flags the contract for deletion.

However, the EVM doesn't delete its bytecode until the end of processing of the transaction. So you won't be able to deploy new bytecode to the same address until the next tx. But you're still able to perform calls on the to-be-destructed contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Destructable {
    function destruct() external {
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}

contract Deployer {
    function deployAndDestruct() external {
        Destructable destructable = new Destructable{salt: keccak256("hello")}();
        destructable.destruct();

        // The second deployment (within the same transation) causes a revert
        // because the bytecode on the desired address is still non-zero
        Destructable destructable2 = new Destructable{salt: keccak256("hello")}();
    }
}
```

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Destructable {
    uint public number = 1;

    function destruct() external {
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
        number++; // not executed after selfdestruct
    }
}

contract Caller {
    Destructable destructable;

    constructor(Destructable _destructable) {
        destructable = _destructable;
    }

    function executeSequence() external {
        destructable.destruct();
    
        // successfully call after the selfestruct was initiated
        uint returnedNumber = destructable.number();
        require(returnedNumber == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please explain what you mean by

"selfdestruct prevents later operations on the contract from being executed"?

I've been wondering about this precise point recently, in particular what would happen if one were to CALL a contract post SELFDESTRUCT. I believe that within that same transaction, opcodes like EXTCODEHASH, EXTCODESIZE, EXTCODECOPY should work the same pre and post SELFDESTRUCT. And I was under the impression that CALLs would, too. Is this wrong ?

Comment: The solidity documentation (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/units-and-global-variables.html) seems to suggest that a contract which executed on a SELFDESTRUCT remains callable as long as the transaction isn't finished "the contract is only really destroyed at the end of the transaction and revert s might “undo” the destruction.

Furthermore, all functions of the current contract are callable directly including the current function."

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks so much for the additional question. My previous statement was partially incorrect, so I edited the answer with clarification and additional code example. As you can see, it does not execute the `number++` statement after `selfdestruct` was initiated - but until the contract is deleted, you can still call it.

Comment: Thanks Petr : ) The fact that the `number++` isn't executed matches my expectation: SELFDESTRUCT triggers the normal halting condition so that execution (of the present execution context) stops immediately.